# C++ STL: Why do STL data structures not provide a function for measuring the memory consumption?

Tags: c++, stl

When deciding about the best data structure for a task, there are three considersions:

- Functionality: Does the data structure provide the operations I need
- Performance: How fast are these operations
- Memory consumption: How much memory does the data structure use

The first consideration can be found by checking the interface of the datastructure, the second can only be measured in a benchmark. However, the third is quite simple if the data structure simply provides a method that calculates the memory it currently uses but hard otherwise.

STL data structures do not such method. But why? It would be very simple to implement such a method for all data structures in STL. For me as the client, it is quite hard to write such a method as I have to be familiar with the internal implementations. In addition, the implementations are hidden behind private members so I cannot access them at all.

So why were they left out? Right now, when choosing the data structure, many other implementations, like the currently released google btree implementation do provide these methods. It is easy to compare these data structures. However, when asking how a STL data structure would perform regarding memory consumption, everything I can basically do is guessing.

I cannot find any reasons why leaving out these methods could be a design decision. In addition, C++ is a language tuned for high performance and low memory footprint. Especially in such a language, I think that assessing the memory consumption of a data structure is a quite usual use case. So I can also not think that they were left out because nobody would use them. In addition, STL is also a quite mature library, so the reason should also not be that the library is just not elaborated enough for this. So what might be the reason for omitting these methods?

Comment: just pass a custom allocator that keeps track of how much it's allocated

Comment: It depends what you mean by "memory consumption".  There's the container itself, then there's the allocator that it uses, then there's `new/malloc`, then there's the OS, then there's the virtual memory system.  Each of these will do some form of memory management, which may lead to more memory being used than would appear to be needed to store `N` things in the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global, no doubt because the container has no way of knowing how much
memory it uses.  It can (and does) have a function which returns the
number of elements it contains, and in cases like `std::vector`, where
the container *overallocates*, it has a function
(`std::vector<>::capacity`) which tells you how many elements it has
allocated.  But it has no way of taking into account any additional
overhead of such allocations (and there is bound to be some).  Such
overhead will depend on the allocator, and usually, on even lower level
functions that the allocator uses.  At the lowest level, it's not even
clear what this means: if I `malloc` one byte, `malloc` is might in
fact allocate 16 according to its concept of "allocation".  But if
`malloc` had no free memory in its pool when I allocated one byte, it
will go to the system, possibly allocating a megabyte or more.  So what
is the memory use in this case: 1 byte, 16 bytes, or a megabyte or more?

Comment: In addition, if any of the values allocates more memory in their constructors or somewhere else, std::vector has no way of knowing that either.

Answer (score 1):

> But why?

Because their task is pure abstraction. `std::vector` is not meant for storing an array of objects **and** telling how much bytes they currently consume in the implementation. It's meant to store an array of objects **only.**

I find this question quite similar (and possibly related) to the ever-recurring "how can I find out how much memory a `malloc()`ated pointer points to" question, and maybe the answer is the same too: you need to keep track of your own stuff. (It may be inconvenient, but that's an other question...)

Comment: I'm not sure the analogy is completely valid.  No amount of keeping track of your own stuff will tell you how much memory a container is using...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see your point, but my reasoning is based on that a container doesn't (and needn't) expose the way it works. If one wants to measure its performance (regarding either memory usage or computational complexity), that requires hacking on the classes, and it's not part of the originally intended functionality. (Or is that not what OP is asking about?)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that.  (Although it is a shame that implementations don't make it easier to benchmark this sort of thing directly.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It is, indeed. This is sacrificing style for functionality, I think... Not necessarily bad, but in this case, it *can* be annoying.